# How to draw a trapezium/trapezoid with react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

this is code by css at id works fine:

```
border-bottom: 100px solid #0000ff80;
border-right: 50px solid transparent;
height: 0;
width: 100px;

<div id="trapezoid"></div>
```

[image]

but my code on react-native doesn't work:

```
<View style={{width:100,height:0,borderBottomWidth:100,borderBottomColor:'#000',borderLeftWidth:0,borderRightWidth:50,borderRightColor:'#000'}}>

</View>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this out

```
var Trapezoid = React.createClass({
 render: function() {
return (
  <View style={styles.trapezoid} />
 )
}
})

trapezoid: {
 width: 200,
 height: 0,
 borderBottomWidth: 100,
 borderBottomColor: 'red',
 borderLeftWidth: 50,
 borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
 borderRightWidth: 50,
 borderRightColor: 'transparent',
 borderStyle: 'solid'
}
```

for more such shapes checkout https://codedaily.io/tutorials/22/The-Shapes-of-React-Native

Comment: is it possible to attach a background to such component? as an <image> with the shape of a trapezoid?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by a rectangle and a triangle in a row.

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
   <View style={styles.rectangle} />
   <View style={[styles.triangle, styles.triangleCornerBottomLeft]} />
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  rectangle: { width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'red' },
  triangle: {
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderRightWidth: 100,
    borderTopWidth: 100,
    borderRightColor: 'transparent',
    borderTopColor: 'red'
  },
  triangleCornerBottomLeft: {
    transform: [
      {rotate: '270deg'}
    ]
  },
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can achieve it by rotating it in x-axis

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={styles.trapezium}></View>
</View>
 
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'gray',
  },
  trapezium: {
    height: 300,
    width: 200,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    transform: [{rotateX: '60deg'}],
  },
});
```