# is it possible to draw trapezoid with border radius in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Here is the actual shape I want to draw using maybe view style properties or are there any alternatives, thanks

[image]

Comment: https://codedaily.io/tutorials/22/The-Shapes-of-React-Native look here

Comment: I need border radius too, hence I've asked similar question to this, but not quite :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54647362/how-to-draw-a-trapezium-trapezoid-with-react-native

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs I would choose something like [react-native-canvas](https://github.com/iddan/react-native-canvas) they have pretty much everything you gonna need to draw. 
Other option would be [GCanvas](https://github.com/alibaba/GCanvas).
With those options you will be able to draw free forms as you wish

But there`s always the option to use SVG as well.

In my past experiences SVG forms solved most of the cases, but sometimes I had to use this canvas libs to draw some more complex or dynamic forms.

Hope this can be of any help to you.